# XSLT to update an attribute given just the new value and XPath to the attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have some code that compares two XML documents for attribute differences (updates only, not new attribute nodes) and generates a set of XPath pointers to the attributes and the new values for the attribute.

**The Setup**

For example, given an old XML and new xml:

*Old XML*

```
<EntityA>
  <EntityB id="foo1" value="bar1" ignoredbutsave="bazz1"/>
</EntityA>
```

*New XML*

```
<EntityA>
  <EntityB id="foo2" value="bar2"/>
</EntityA>
```

My code would return

```
/EntityA/EntityB/@id, foo2
/EntityA/EntityB/@value, bar2
```

I would like to generate an XSLT that merges the old XML into the new XML, to create the following XML:

```
<EntityA>
  <EntityB id="foo2" value="bar2" ignoredbutsave="bazz1"/>
</EntityA>
```

All answers I've found on SO assume some prior knowledge about the attribute name.   In this case, I'm given only the XPath reference the attribute, not the name itself.  I know I could parse the XPath string to derive the attribute name, but would prefer to keep that complexity out of the code.

**What I've tried**

I can't use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) because I need to copy the `ignoredbutsave` attribute from the old XML.  I've tried to use an xsl:param to select the attribute name from the XPath and use it within an xsl:attribute, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/EntityA/EntityB/@id">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       <xsl:param name="newValue" select="name(/EntityA/EntityB/@id)"/>
         <xsl:attribute name="$newValue">newAttributeId</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/EntityA/EntityB/@value">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       <xsl:param name="myattrname" select="name(/EntityA/EntityB/@value)"/>
         <xsl:attribute name="$myattrname">newAttributeValue</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this causes the error `The value '$myattrname' of the attribute 'name' is not a valid QName.`

So, the question is *given an XPath for an attribute and a new value for that attribute, how do I generate an an XSLT that updates that value without explicitly referencing the attribute name?*

Comment: Have you tried to put your `$myattrname` in curly brackets?

Comment: @MarcusRickert - yes `<xsl:attribute name="{$myattrname}">` does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/EntityA/EntityB/@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">foo2</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/EntityA/EntityB/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">bar2</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to your old XML:**

```
<EntityA>
  <EntityB id="foo1" value="bar1" ignoredbutsave="bazz1"/>
</EntityA>
```

**Yields your old XML with the required attribute value substitutions made:**

```
<EntityA>
  <EntityB id="foo2" value="bar2" ignoredbutsave="bazz1"/>
</EntityA>
```

Comment: Thanks, kjhughes, that did it.   `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">bar2</xsl:attribute>` (no dot in `name()`) also works.

Comment: @lreeder, good suggestion regarding the dropping the `.` in `name()`.  Cleaner.  Answer updated.

Comment: The answer may need modification if it is to work on namespace-prefixed attributes.